# React authentication using fetch

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest, passport.js, fetch-api

I created my REST Api user authentication with passportjs, the authentication  is working well with postman. But when i tried integrating the backend with my react App the authentication is not working, i can't seems to figure the solution my code is

i'm using fetch Api for sending the request to the backend, also in my react App i included in package.json `proxy` `localhost:5000`. and the route for the login is /user/login

```js
constructor(props){
    super(props);
      this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      token: '',
      email: '',
      password: '',
      signInError: []
    };

    this.onTextBoxEmail = this.onTextBoxEmail.bind(this);
    this.onTextBoxPassword = this.onTextBoxPassword.bind(this);
    this.onSignIn = this.onSignIn.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
  
  }

   onTextBoxEmail(event){ this.setState({email: event.target.value,})}
   onTextBoxPassword(event){this.setState({ password: event.target.value,})}

   onSignIn () {
    const {
      email,
      password,
    } = this.state;
    fetch('/user/login', {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email: email,
        password: password,
      })
    }).then(res => console.log(res))
   }

  render() { 
    const {
      email,
      password,
    } = this.state
    return (
      <>
        <div className="container">
          <Row className="py-5" >
          <Col md="6" className="offset-1 mx-auto py-5" >
            <Card className="card-user">

                <CardText className="py-3 px-3">
                  <div className="card-description">
                     <CardBody>
                     <h2 className="text-center"> Sign In</h2>
                  <Form>
                      <Col className="pl-md-1" md="12">
                        <FormGroup>
                          <Input
                            value={email}
                            placeholder="mike@email.com"
                            type="email"
                            onChange={this.onTextBoxEmail}
                             />
                        </FormGroup>
                      </Col>
                    <Col className="pl-md-1" md="12">
                        <FormGroup>
                          <Input
                            value={password}
                            placeholder="Password"
                            type="password"
                            onChange={this.onTextBoxPassword}
                          />
                        </FormGroup>
                      </Col>
                    <CardFooter>
                  <div className="button-container  py-3">
                    <Button 
                    className="btn-fill" 
                    color="primary" 
                    type="submit"
                    onClick={this.onSignIn}
                    >
                      Sign in
                    </Button>
                  </div>
                  <p> Don't have Account. Sign up <a href="register"> here </a> </p>
                </CardFooter>
                  </Form>
```

Comment: "it's not working" is not enough information. What's happening to the page (does it reload by any chance...), is the network request being made (check the network tab in the console)?

Comment: I think it is the problem with network request

Comment: so what do you see in the console? Does the request get send, if so what is the response?

Comment: from the server i made console.log(req.user) if the user is successfully authenticated i will some detail is not then it will return undefined. Every time i refresh the page i see undefined on the server console

Comment: your authentication request is made when you click the button, not when the page is loaded. Open the browser console (f12), click the network tab, then click the button in your page and see what happens